# How does freertos works on Arduino in order to interupt tasks

Tags: freertos

I have tried freertos on Arduino in order to run several tasks in parallel.

It works great and i want to understand freertos internals. I have looked into source code and i have a lot of questions !

First of all, i suppose there is a scheduler which is stopping (pause) current task and resuming another.

- I did not find in Freertos source code anything that can pause program. Can anyone tell me how it works ?
- If i work with String data type in my program, it does not work. What is spectific to String type causing bug with Freertos ?
- Freertos seems to execute some code even if i just include freertos.h file (even if there is nothing else). Where is this code and how freertos does to add initialisation code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have the source code, so I suggest stepping through it to answer most of these questions yourself.  I'm afraid they are too broad an non specific to even begin answering here.  https://www.freertos.org/FAQ-how-to-use-the-FreeRTOS-support-forum.html

(I love the assertion that problems with strings must be a problem in FreeRTOS, like nobody else has used strings before ;o)

Comment: If Strings exists, it might work. If nobody else use strings, why does this datatype avaiable ?